# How do i get this to compile for x64

Tags: c, pointers, struct, malloc, 64-bit

This compiles fine in x86, but when I used it in x64 configuration the x and y variables do not have an address when I try to access them? Do need some sort of padding to align to a larger address? Using MSVC..

```
#define ARR_SIZE 25

typedef struct {
    unsigned int x;
    unsigned int y;
}Stuff;

void allocateArray(Stuff *stuffArr) {

    Stuff *stuff = malloc(sizeof (Stuff) * ARR_SIZE);

    for (int i = 0; i < ARR_SIZE; i++) {
        (*(stuff + i)) = (Stuff) { i, i + i };
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < ARR_SIZE; i++) {
        printf("%d : %d\n", (stuff + i)->x, (stuff + i)->y);
    }

    stuffArr = stuff;
}

void deallocateArray(Stuff *stuffArr) {
    free(stuffArr);
}

int main(){
    Stuff * stuff = NULL;

    allocateArray(stuff);
    deallocateArray(stuff);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It shouldn't work for either architecture. The line `stuffArr = stuff;` changes the local copy of `stuffArr`. It has no effect on variable `stuff` in `main`.

Comment: Also, `(*(stuff + i))` is the same as `stuff[i]`, and `(stuff + i)->x` is just `stuff[i].x`

Comment: _the x and y variables do not have an address when I try to access them_ : what is that supposed to mean ?

Comment: This is such a FAQ bug. Let me see if I can find a duplicate.

Comment: This cannot work for the reasons pointed out in the comments and answers. The code you were running when it worked is not the code you show us here.

Comment: Apparently we have no canonical duplicate for this... we should probably create one, since this is such a common bug.

Comment: There, [I made one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39486797/dynamic-memory-access-only-works-inside-function).

Comment: @MichaelWalz Changed it up, still same error [screenshots](http://imgur.com/a/WeLJW) and [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/By8szrqp)

Comment: This compiles ok, but is a program with errors.  Variables are pased in C by value, so you cannot expect the pointer you pass to the function in `main` to be modified by the function.  It can compile ok in 32bit, but it cannot work as you expect anywhere.

Comment: @spatmac the version in [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/By8szrqp) is just plain wrong. See the answers below.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Whiskers down there figured it out, thank you for taking time to look at it, turns I needed another std include

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I copied and pasted your code into Visual Studio 2015 and compiled in both x86 and x64 and got the exact same output both times, however like user3386109 said, you aren't actually changing the variable `stuff` in `main`.

You could also use array indexing instead of adding integers to pointers like this.

```
for (int i = 0; i < ARR_SIZE; i++) {
    stuff[i] = (Stuff) { i, i + i };
}

for (int i = 0; i < ARR_SIZE; i++) {
    printf("%d : %d\n", stuff[i].x, stuff[i].y);
}
```

Comment: I just dont konw what the deal is, i changed it up to get rid of the goofy pointers and it wont compile as x64 [screenshots](http://imgur.com/a/WeLJW) and [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/By8szrqp)

Comment: You are missing `#include <stdlib.h>`. I copied your code from pastebin into visual studio, set the exact same project settings, and had same results as you, but then I noticed you were missing `stdlib.h`, added that in, and then it worked just fine in x64. Why it worked in x86 without `stdlib.h`, I do not know.

Comment: This has been bugging me for a day and a half.. Thanks a ton!!!

Comment: No problem! If I had to guess why it worked in x86, Windows/MSVC probably has a default 32 bit implementation built in for functions like `malloc` and `free`, but doesn't have defaults for 64 bit. In general, always remember to include `stdlib.h` when doing dynamic memory allocation.

Answer (score 4):

As user3386109 says, the code is not correct. Probably you are expecting that the `allocateArray()` function returns the allocated pointer, while you are passing the pointer by value, so that the variable `stuff` inside `main()` won't be updated.

You could either:

- change the `allocateArray()` signature to `void allocateArray(Stuff **stuffArr)`
- change the `allocateArray()` signature to `Stuff *allocateArray()`

(imho the second would be more idiomatic and clear).

I'd write it as:

```
Stuff *allocateArray(size_t count) {
    Stuff *stuff = (Stuff *) malloc(sizeof (Stuff) * count);

    if (! stuff)
        return NULL;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        stuff[i].x = i;
        stuff[i].y = 2 * i;

        printf("%d : %d\n", stuff[i].x, stuff[i].y);
    }

    return stuff;
}

void deallocateArray(Stuff *stuffArr) {
    if (stuffArr)
        free(stuffArr);
}

int main(){
    Stuff * stuff = allocateArray(ARR_SIZE);
    deallocateArray(stuff);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I just dont konw what the deal is, i changed it up to get rid of the goofy pointers and it wont compile as x64 [screenshots](http://imgur.com/a/WeLJW) and [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/By8szrqp)

Answer (score 2):

When you pass stuff in allocateArray you create a local variable, and when you remplace it at the end of the function, the variable in main is not updated

This should work, you just lost your pointer in the allocateArray function

```
#define ARR_SIZE 25

typedef struct {
    unsigned int x;
    unsigned int y;
}Stuff;

Stuff *allocateArray() {

   Stuff *stuff = malloc(sizeof (Stuff) * ARR_SIZE);

   for (int i = 0; i < ARR_SIZE; i++) {
       (*(stuff + i)) = (Stuff) { i, i + i };
   }

   for (int i = 0; i < ARR_SIZE; i++) {
       printf("%d : %d\n", (stuff + i)->x, (stuff + i)->y);
   }

   return stuff;
}

void deallocateArray(Stuff *stuffArr) {
  free(stuffArr);
}

int main(){
  Stuff * stuff = NULL;

  stuff = allocateArray();
  deallocateArray(stuff);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The good question is how does it works in x86. (it is undefined behavior).
Try this:

```
#define ARR_SIZE 25
#include  "stdlib.h"
#include  "stdio.h"
typedef struct {
    unsigned int x;
    unsigned int y;
}Stuff;

void * allocateArray(Stuff *stuffArr) { //this row

    Stuff *stuff = (Stuff*)malloc(sizeof (Stuff) * ARR_SIZE);

    for (int i = 0; i < ARR_SIZE; i++) {
        (*(stuff + i)) = (Stuff) { i, i + i };
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < ARR_SIZE; i++) {
        printf("%d : %d\n", (stuff + i)->x, (stuff + i)->y);
    }

    stuffArr = stuff;
    return stuff; //this row
}

void deallocateArray(Stuff *stuffArr) {
    free(stuffArr);
}

int main(){
    Stuff * stuff = NULL;
    printf("%d\n",stuff);
    stuff=(Stuff*)allocateArray(stuff); ///this row
    printf("%p\n",stuff);
    deallocateArray(stuff);
    printf("%p\n",stuff);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I just dont konw what the deal is, i changed it up to get rid of the goofy pointers and it wont compile as x64 [screenshots](http://imgur.com/a/WeLJW) and [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/By8szrqp)