# Dynamic memory access only works inside function

Tags: c, malloc, parameter-passing, dynamic-memory-allocation, pass-by-value

This question is meant to be used as a canonical duplicate for this FAQ:

I am allocating data dynamically inside a function and everything works well, but only inside the function where the allocation takes place. When I attempt to use the same data outside the function, I get crashes or other unexpected program behavior.

Here is a [MCVE:](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void create_array (int* data, int size)
{
  data = malloc(sizeof(*data) * size);
  for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
  {
    data[i] = i;
  }

  print_array(data, size);
}

void print_array (int* data, int size)
{
  for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
  {
    printf("%d ", data[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");
}

int main (void)
{
  int* data;
  const int size = 5;

  create_array(data, size);
  print_array(data, size);  // crash here

  free(data);
}
```

Whenever `print_array` is called from inside the `create_array` function, I get the expected output `0 1 2 3 4`, but when I call it from `main`, I get a program crash.

What is the reason for this?

Comment: I almost downvoted you for making such a stupid mistake :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Unfortunately I haven't found a way to make the question a community wiki, only the answer. I've poked the mods, so hopefully it will get converted to community wiki soon.

Comment: I think can be better hosted on Documentation Beta.

Comment: @LPs By all means, feel free to copy/pasta it over there. You can't use a Documentation page for close-as-duplicate though. Nor will it pop up when people post a new question nor search for the answer themselves.

Comment: @RestlessC0bra No, there's nothing wrong with this code. Don't use broken compilers/static analysers. The particular error you describe is a typical, well-known "false positive", it is a common bug found in many tools.

Comment: @RestlessC0bra False positives = tool bugs = broken tool. VS2015 is a C++ compiler. In C mode, it is very much broken and everyone knows it. It does not conform to the C standard, nor does it conform to the previous C standard from 1999, nor does it conform to the ancient C90/ANSI standard. It is also well-known to whine about perfectly fine C code, since Microsoft think they alone should have the authority to dictate which language features that are good and bad, rather than the C standard committee.

Comment: @Lundin I would give you bounty for your comment if I could!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The reason for this bug is that the `data` used by the `create_array` function is a local variable that only exists inside that function. The assigned memory address obtained from `malloc` is only stored in this local variable and never returned to the caller.

---

Consider this simple example:

```
void func (int x)
{
  x = 1;
  printf("%d", x);
}

...
int a;
func(a);
printf("%d", a); // bad, undefined behavior - the program might crash or print garbage
```

Here, a *copy* of the variable `a` is stored locally inside the function, as the parameter `x`. This is known as *pass-by-value*.

When `x` is modified, only that local variable gets changed. The variable `a` in the caller remains unchanged, and since `a` is not initialized, it will contain "garbage" and cannot be reliably used.

---

Pointers are no exception to this pass-by-value rule. In your example, the pointer variable `data` is passed by value to the function. The `data` pointer inside the function is a local copy and the assigned address from `malloc` is never passed back to the caller.

So the pointer variable in the caller remains uninitialized and therefore the program crashes. In addition, the `create_array` function has also created a *memory leak*, since after that function execution, there is no longer any pointer in the program keeping track of that chunk of allocated memory.

---

There are two ways you can modify the function to work as expected. Either by returning a copy of the local variable back to the caller:

```
int* create_array (int size)
{
  int* data = malloc(sizeof(*data) * size);
  for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
  {
    data[i] = i;
  }

  print_array(data, size);

  return data;
}

int main (void)
{
  int* data;
  const int size = 5;

  data = create_array(size);
  print_array(data, size);
}
```

or by passing the address to the caller's pointer variable and write directly to the caller variable:

```
void create_array (int** data, int size)
{
  int* tmp = malloc(sizeof(*tmp) * size);
  for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
  {
    tmp[i] = i;
  }

  *data = tmp;      
  print_array(*data, size);
}

int main (void)
{
  int* data;
  const int size = 5;

  create_array(&data, size);
  print_array(data, size);
}
```

Either form is fine.