# How to make a function to read an array in c?

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

I have to write function to read the array length and the array and make that array able to be used in other functions.

I have read many things about pointers but I didn`t find an answer to my question.
Here is my code.

```
int readArray(int *ar, int *pointer){
    int i, length;
    scanf("%d", &length);
    ar = (int *) malloc(length * sizeof(int));
    for(i = 0; i < length; i++){
        scanf("%d", pointer + i);
    }
    return length;
}

void printArray(int *pointer, int length){
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < length; i++){
        printf("%d ", *(pointer + i));
    }
}

int main(){
    int *pointer, *ar, length;
    pointer = ar[0];//Here I get the warnings.
    length = readArray(ar, pointer);
    printArray(pointer, length);
    return 0;
}
```

The warnings in codeblocks:
`warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast`
and
`warning: 'ar' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]|`.

This question is different from this [Dynamic memory access only works inside function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39486797/dynamic-memory-access-only-works-inside-function) because i have to read the array length in the readArray function. And for me, as a begginer, only little difference is a big difference.

Comment: `pointer = &ar[0];` or `pointer = ar;` and warning will disappear. But this does not mean program will work.

Comment: still the 2nd warning (warning: 'ar' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]) at the same code line

Comment: So initialize it.

Comment: I know how to initialize a pointer to point to a variable(int *p, a; p = &a) but I`m stuck here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would consider with 2 options. One returns pointer to array and saves length as pointer and another returns length but accepts pointer to pointer as parameter.

### Option 1: Return pointer of array and pass pointer to length parameter

This option will return pointer to allocated and filled array and length will be saved to pointer passed as parameter

```
int* readArray(int* length) {
    int* arr;
    //Scan for length
    scanf("%d", length);
    //Allocate memory
    arr = (int *)malloc(...);
    //Fill data
    ...
    return arr;
}
```

and I will use it like this:

```
int length;
int *pointer;

pointer = readArray(&length);
printArray(pointer, length);
```

---

### Option 2: Pass pointer to pointer to array and return length of array

```
int readArray(int ** ar) {
    int length;
    ....
    *ar = (int *)malloc(...);
    ...
    return length;
}
```

Usage:

```
int* ar;
int length;

length = readArray(&ar);
printArray(ar, length);
```

I would go with this option.

Answer (score 1):

You actually want this:

```
int readArray(int **ar) {
  int i, length;
  scanf("%d", &length);
  *ar = (int *)malloc(length * sizeof(int));
  for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    scanf("%d", &(*ar)[i]);
  }
  return length;
}

void printArray(int *pointer, int length) {
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    printf("%d ", *(pointer + i));
  }
}

int main() {
  int *ar, length;
  length = readArray(&ar);
  printArray(ar, length);
  return 0;
}
```

Variables are passed by value in C, included pointers. With your solution:

```
int readArray(int *ar, int *pointer){
    int i, length;
    scanf("%d", &length);
    ar = (int *) malloc(length * sizeof(int));
    for(i = 0; i < length; i++){
        scanf("%d", pointer + i);
    }
    return length;
}
```

`ar` is a local variable to `readArray` and `pointer` will never get modified in `main`.

Consider this:

```
void foo(int bar)
{
  bar = 123;
}

...
int a = 1;
foo(a);
// a won't contain 123 here
```

Comment: This `&(*ar)[i]` confused me. I do not understand this.

Comment: @Timotei  `ar` is a pointer to a pointer to `int`. `*ar` is a pointer to `int`, actually here it is the pointer to the `length` `int`s allocated by `malloc`. `(*ar)[n]` is the nth `int` of the `int`s mentioned before. `&(*ar)[n]` is the _pointer_ to the nth `int`.

Comment: How would you write a function to read the array in the exactly the same way you did in the above comment and to print the array(in the same function).

Comment: @Timotei not quite sure I understood your question. Maybe you should post another question.

Comment: I mean how would the function void printArray(int **pointer, int length) look? Note de the **pointer not *pointer.