# read matrix issue C language

Tags: c, matrix

This code should read and display a matrix. But it doesnt work, I cant find the problem.  Why it doesnt work?

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX 100

void read_matrix(int a[MAX][MAX], int n)
{
    int i, j;

    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
            scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);
}

int main(void)
{
    int a[MAX][MAX], n = 1, i, j;

    read_matrix(a, n);

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
            printf("%d ", a[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

For input:

```
2
1 2
3 4
```

The output is:

```
1
```

Comment: Do some research about *emulate pass by reference in C*.

Comment: 3rd time someone asks this question today. Is there a canonical duplicate for "Why doesn't my main program work when I alter local variables inside a function only?" Close one but not quite a duplicate: [Dynamic memory access only works inside function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39486797/dynamic-memory-access-only-works-inside-function)

Answer (score 2):

Because `n` is passed by *value*, not by reference. Use:

```
void read_matrix(int a[MAX][MAX], int *n) {
    int i, j;

    scanf("%d", n);
    for (i = 0; i < *n; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < *n; j++)
            scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);
}
```

and

```
read_matrix(a, &n);
```

Now `n` is passed by reference and it should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, let's deal with a fact ***"In C there is nothing called pass by reference"*.**

But yes we emulate that with what is available in C, that is pass by value.

So in the first case there are things that happened

- You call the function like this `read_matrix(a, n);`
- A copy of the variable is there in `read_matrix`.
- We make changes to the copy.
- Function ends and story ends there. That local variable's scope ends. It is not alive now.
- You come back to `main()`. Do you expect to see any change in `n`? Nope. Because all change was there in `read_matrix`.

Now to change that we write it this way.

```
void read_matrix(int a[MAX][MAX], int* nn)
{
    if( scanf("%d", nn) != 1){
        fprintf(stderr,"Error in input");
        exit(1);
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < *nn; i++)
        for (size_t j = 0; j < *nn; j++)
            if( scanf("%d", &a[i][j]) != 1){
                fprintf(stderr,"Error in input");
                exit(1);
            }
}
```

Now here also couple of things happened

- You pass the `&n` or the address of `n`.
- Then `nn` is a local variable (local to `read_matrix`) containing the address of `n`.
- `scanf()` wants the address of what it will write something.
- We pass the address of `n` or content of `nn`.
- Then `scanf()` writes where? In the memory of `n`. So `n` in `main()` changes.
- Now we want to get while looping the value of `n` or the value in address of `n` or the value in the address contained by `nn`.
- So we use `*` on `nn`. Or `*nn`.
- Now you back to `main()` and the local variable `nn` is not there and it's lifetime ended when the function `read_matrix` ended.
- You see the changed value in `n`.

---

#### Do you see any difference in two method?

In one we pass the value. In another we pass as value the address of `n`.

Both are pass by value. But in second method due to the side effect of accessing memory we see he change in `main()`. Story ends.