# Modifying a string being passed as argument of a function in C

Tags: c, string, pointers

How can I **modify** the value of a string **being passed as argument** in a function?

For example I have this function `foo` (that is supposed to change the value of `return_string` from `"old string"` to `"new string"`):

```
int foo(char *return_string) {
    char *tmp = "new string";
    return_string = tmp;
    return 0;
}
```

But if I call it in the following way:

```
char *s = "old string";
foo(s);
printf("%s\n", s);
```

I still get `old string` as output. Why?

I admit I have a little of confusion with pointers and strings in C.

Comment: Not exact dupe, but same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39486797/694733

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### The problem

In the function `foo()`:

```
int foo(char *return_string) {
    char *tmp = "new string";
    return_string = tmp;
    return 0;
}
```

You are just assigning the pointer `tmp` to the pointer `return_string`. The parameter `return_string` is passed by value to `foo()` (i.e.: it is a copy of what the caller passed). Neither what `return_string` is pointing to (which may be what you want) nor the pointer passed is being modified.

---

#### `strcpy()`

Consider using `strcpy()` instead:

```
int foo(char *return_string) {
    char *tmp = "new string";
    strcpy(return_string, tmp);
    return 0;
}
```

This will modify the contents of the string pointed by `return_string`.

---

#### Passing the pointer by reference

Passing the pointer by reference, will make possible the modification of the pointer pointing to the string:

```
int foo(char **return_string) {
    char *tmp = "new string";
    *return_string = tmp;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `return_string = &tmp;` should be `*return_string = tmp;`

Comment: @mch `tmp` has automatic storage duration, so it does not exist after leaving the function. It didn't make sense at all.

Comment: `*return_string = tmp;` is okay, if `tmp` points to a string literal. Using `&tmp` is dangerous.

Comment: If I'm passing the pointer by reference should I call `foo` in such a way? `char *s = "old string"; foo(&s); printf("%s\n", s);`

Comment: Yes, in order to pass the pointer `s` by reference, use `foo(&s)` (i.e.: pass the address of the pointer).

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the pointer by value. You need to pass the pointer by reference.

Change the function interface to pass a `char** return_string` instead of a `char* return_string`.
And then do `*return_string = tmp;`.

Answer (score 0):

Provided that your strings are dynamically allocated, it might be implemented as follows

```
int foo(char **return_string) {
    if (*return string) free(*return_string)
    *return_string = strdup("new string");
    return 0;
}

char* s = strdup("original");
foo(&s);
....
```

Comment: nothing guarantees that the argument is dynamically allocated.

Comment: try `char *test="hello"; foo(&hello);` => BANG! the caller is responsible for the memory leak when passing a pointer on a pointer.

Comment: Yes of course. You will need some agreement on how do you allocate your strings. If you use dynamic allocation, it's the most universal solution (you will need to avoid storing constants, but it's not the worst restriction. Say, when you use strcpy - based approach, you'll need to worry about buffer size. All options have their drawbacks. The best solution might be your own string container with an explicit deallocator pointer.. but it's probably beyond the scope of the question in hand.