# Can't get the reason for segfault

Tags: c, malloc, dynamic-arrays

EDIT : Note that **It's not that I can't access the memory allocated by `storeContents()` in `main()` if you think so. Program crashes during the execution of `storeContents()`**

The program fails here :

```
strcpy(contents[count], dir->d_name);
printf("Stored %s(out hiddenVisible)\n", dir->d_name); // for testing
```

It's `strcpy()` not the `printf()`, I added it just for the reference.

The debugger(gdb) says :

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7f3cd72 in __strcpy_ssse3 () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
```

I am making a program that involves the following function "storeContents"(It stores contents' names of a directory in a dynamic array). There are two issues with this function : (1) It says "**Stored *file_name*" twice** for the **first** file and (2) says "**Segmentation fault**". I can't figure out either of them. Thanks for your efforts!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <limits.h>

static short hiddenVisible = 0;

/* Store directory's contents in **contents */
static char ** storeContents(struct dirent *dir, DIR *dirp, unsigned numOfContents);
/* Count files/directories in a directory */
static unsigned getNumOfContents(struct dirent *dir, DIR *dirp);

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    char **contents;
    DIR *dirp;
    struct dirent *dir;
    unsigned numOfContents;

    dirp = opendir("/home/gaurav");
    if((dir = readdir(dirp)) == NULL) {
        perror("readdir");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* Getting number of files/directories */
    numOfContents = getNumOfContents(dir, dirp);
    printf("There are %u files.\n", numOfContents);

    /* To position again to the first entry */
    rewinddir(dirp);

    contents = storeContents(dir, dirp, numOfContents);

    /* Print contents */
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < numOfContents; ++i)
        printf("%s\n", contents[i]);

    closedir(dirp);
    return 0;
}

char **
storeContents(struct dirent *dir, DIR *dirp, unsigned numOfContents) {

    char **contents;
    unsigned count = 0;

    /* Allocating memory for entries */
    contents = malloc(numOfContents * sizeof(*contents));

    /* Allocating memory for each '*contents' */
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < numOfContents; i++)
        contents[i] = (char *)malloc(NAME_MAX); /* we know char is 1 byte, so no "sizeof" */

    while(count < numOfContents) {
        /* Ignore "." and ".." */
        if(!(strcmp(dir->d_name, ".")) || !(strcmp(dir->d_name, ".."))) {
            if((dir = readdir(dirp)) == NULL) {
                perror("readdir");
                exit(1);
            }
            continue;
        }

        if(hiddenVisible) {
            strcpy(contents[count], dir->d_name);
            if((dir = readdir(dirp)) == NULL) {
                perror("readdir");
                exit(1);
            }
            count++;
        } else {
            if(dir->d_name[0] == '.')
                if((dir = readdir(dirp)) == NULL) {
                    perror("readdir");
                    exit(1);
                }
                else {
                    strcpy(contents[count], dir->d_name);
                    if((dir = readdir(dirp)) == NULL) {
                        perror("readdir");
                        exit(1);
                    }
                    count++;
                }
        }
    }
    return contents;
}

unsigned
getNumOfContents(struct dirent *dir, DIR *dirp) {

    unsigned count = 0;

    while(dir) {
        if(hiddenVisible) {
            /* Ignore "." and ".." */
            if(!(strcmp(dir->d_name, ".")) || !(strcmp(dir->d_name, ".."))) {
                if((dir = readdir(dirp)) == NULL) {
                    perror("readdir a");
                    exit(1);
                }
                continue;
            }
            count++;
            if((dir = readdir(dirp)) == NULL) {
                perror("readdir b");
                exit(1);
            }
        } else {
            if(dir->d_name[0] == '.') {
                if((dir = readdir(dirp)) == NULL) {
                    perror("readdir c");
                    exit(1);
                }
            }
                else {
                    count++;
                    if((dir = readdir(dirp)) == NULL) {
                        perror("readdir d");
                        exit(1);
                    }
                }
        }
    }

    return count;
}
```

Comment: Please make a [mcve] or your question will be closed.

Comment: I added just one function. I ripped off all the unnecessary stuff.

Comment: And use a debugger to find the line where it segfaults.

Comment: You ripped off more than the unnecessary. Create a minimal main function that reproduces the problems.

Comment: I added the link. Anyway, let me edit

Comment: Segmentation faults usually occurs when you try to access the memory location that is not available for the user.

Comment: @Vaibhav Yeah, I do know that but can't figure out where exactly I am doing that.

Comment: You can either use gdb or put some printf statements to narrow down scope where it is failing.

Comment: Again, please stop changing the question by fixing the bugs. The point of asking a question here is for others to point out the bugs, so if you change it as you go, you invalidate posted answers. I've done a rollback of your recent edits.

Comment: Yeah I am changing the program, but it didn't work so, I changed the question as well. Anyway it's the third `readdir` in `getNumOfContents()` that fails. Can you help me with that?

Comment: but it was fine before, it's failing after I edited it.

Comment: No, I'm giving up my attempts to salvage this question. Good luck.

Comment: @Lundin It's done mate. Sorry, was quite busy last few days. `readdir()` returns `NULL` when it fails and when the stream is ended as well. The original solution was the **second point** in your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some bugs:

- `contents` is a local parameter to the function, it will not get returned to main(). See [Dynamic memory access only works inside function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39486797/dynamic-memory-access-only-works-inside-function).
- `contents = (char **)malloc(numOfContents);` is wrong, you need to allocate room for `numOfContents` pointers. Change this to `contents = malloc(numOfContents * sizeof(*contents))`.
- You should check each call to readdir and make sure it doesn't return `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

`contents` in the function `storeContents` is a local copy of `contents` from `main`.

Changing it in the function does not change the variable in `main`.

You should return the array. Change
`static void storeContents(struct dirent *dir, DIR *dirp, char **contents, unsigned numOfContents);`
to
`static char **storeContents(struct dirent *dir, DIR *dirp, unsigned numOfContents);`

,`return contents;` in the function and call it like `char **contents = storeContents(...);`

Comment: I think I am doing the same you're saying. And btw, control never goes back to `main()`, It all happens inside `storeContents()`

Comment: The variable disappears, but not where it points to, if it is malloced. Like when you return an int, the int is gone, but the value is returned to the caller.

Comment: @Gaurav This is the reason why. `contents` in main() never gets set, and that's that. Common FAQ, see the linked duplicate.

Comment: @Lundin Please! Just hear me this one time : The control is never returned to `main()`, `segfault` crashes the program when the execution of `storeContents()` is on going. In other words, **It's not that I can't access that memory in `main()`, I can't even access in `storeContents()`, actually I can but just till 4 iterations of the loop.** And even if if I follow your **DUPLICATE OF** suggestion, it doesn't work. Everything is still same.

Comment: @Gaurav You should make that obvious by editing the question then. Like pointing out which line the program crashes on when you run it through your debugger. It seems likely that this program has numerous bugs, we found one of them, might be others.

Comment: @Gaurav I'm guessing readdir is returning NULL but you aren't checking if it was successful. What's the value of `dir` before the program crashes?

Comment: I added the line reference.

Comment: @Gaurav I've re-opened the question. But please note that the bug pointed out definitely needs to be fixed too.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Will do that. Btw, as you asked : `dir` is `4038058936` just before it fails and `4038058968` where it fails.

Comment: @Gaurav You don't need to fix the bugs in the question (that's what it is about), just in the real program :) Anyway I found a second severe bug which is likely the cause, posted an answer.