# Segmentation fault occurs when accessing records in a dynamic array in the main function, but not in the included function

Tags: c, data-structures, segmentation-fault

I came across the problem where a dynamic array of structures is properly initialized and filled with data in a function from an included file, but an attempt to access the content of the array causes segmentation faults in the main function even though the pointer was defined globally. Please have a look at the example below:

**my_struct.h**

```
typedef struct my_struct {
    int one;
    int two;
} my_struct_t;

void update_my_struct(my_struct_t*, int);
```

**my_struct.c**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "my_struct.h"

void
update_my_struct(my_struct_t *my_s, int num)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < num; i++ ) {
        my_s = realloc(my_s, sizeof(my_struct_t)*(i+1));
        my_s[i].one = 1*i;
        my_s[i].two = 2*i;
    }
    printf("  my_s[0] one: %d two: %d\n", my_s[0].one, my_s[0].two);
}
```

**main.c**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "my_struct.h"

my_struct_t *my_structs;

void
main(void)
{
    int i;
    update_my_struct(my_structs, 4);
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        printf("  %d. one = %d, two = %d\n", i, my_structs[i].one, my_structs[i].two);
    free(my_structs);
}
```

Compile and run:

```
$ gcc main.c my_struct.c
$ ./a.out 
  my_s[0] one: 0 two: 0
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I checked with gdb and the seg fault occurs in `main`, so it puzzles me how come the dynamic array can be accessed in the included function, but in the main function even though the pointer was declared in `main.c`. I will appreciate some helpful hints and comments on this issue.

**update**

Following up on EML's answer I changed the code of the update function to:

```
void
update_my_struct(my_struct_t *my_s, int num)
{
        int i;

        for (i = 0; i < num; i++ ) {
                if (my_s == NULL)
                        my_s = (my_struct_t *) malloc(sizeof(my_struct_t));
                else
                        my_s = (my_struct_t *) realloc(my_s, sizeof(my_struct_t)*(i+1));
                my_s[i].one = 1*i;
                my_s[i].two = 2*i;
        }
        printf("  my_s[3] one: %d two: %d\n", my_s[3].one, my_s[3].two);
}
```

Seg fault still occurs:

```
$ ./a.out 
  my_s[3] one: 3 two: 6
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Valgrind did not provide me with any insightful information, here is the snippet of its output:

```
==5301== Using Valgrind-3.15.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==5301== Command: ./a.out
==5301== 
  my_s[3] one: 3 two: 6
==5301== Invalid read of size 4
==5301==    at 0x40118F: main (in a.out)
==5301==  Address 0x4 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==5301== 
==5301== 
==5301== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV): dumping core
...
```

Comment: Where is the `malloc`?

Comment: Where is `update_my_struct`?  If you have a bug in a function, you need to show that function in your post.

Comment: You probably wrongly copied twice my_struct.h instead of popsting actual code of my_struct.c

Comment: It would be a lot easier if you posted the actual code.  But even only seeing half of it, I can make a good guess as to what's going on.  Most likely `update_my_struct` is allocating memory, initializing it, then returning it, without updating the global `my_structs`, which will remain `NULL`.  When accessed, this results in a segmentation fault.

Comment: `my_struct.c` you posted is actually `my_struct.h`. Please [edit] the question.

Comment: Edit made, code fixed. Thanks for pointing it out everyone.

Comment: @mac13k When you wrote "Edit made, code fixed.", did you mean you have fixed the original problem? Because the code is still broken.

Comment: Your function only changes the function parameter `my_struct_t *my_s`. The global still remains with its original value (random or undefined). One way is to return the pointer from the function and assign it to the global, or pass a `my_struct_s **` to the function, and then modify the code to access the global via this pointer to pointer. It would also be good to check the return value of `realloc`. Also, `realloc` will crash because of the initial undefined value of the pointer passed to it.

Comment: @DNT How a double pointer would be any better if I am dealing with a dynamic array of structs that are not dynamic?

Comment: @mak13k It's not a matter of being better or worse. It is one method of accessing your global via the pointer to pointer. You still need to initialize your global to NULL since it is not guaranteed that its initial value will be NULL. An uninitialized variable according to the standard has a  `undefined` value. However, I think you need to reconsider the design, so that you keep track of how many structs you have in your array unless you only initialize it once.

Comment: If you compile with `-g` (eg. `gcc -g main.c my_struct.c`), you can probably get more useful information fram `valgrind`.  And you should probably also include warnings (`gcc -g -Wall -Wextra -pedantic main.c my_struct.c`), although in this case I think they wonʼt help with the issue.

Comment: Also, that valgrind output *is* helpful: the “Address 0x4” part of “Address 0x4 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd” says that you are working near a NULL pointer somewhere (since 0x4 is just 4 bytes off 0x0 aka NULL).

Comment: It is not a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39486797 !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I implied in my comments. This assumes `*my_s` is initially NULL, so `realloc` in that case will act like `malloc`.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "my_struct.h"

void
update_my_struct(my_struct_t **my_s, int num)
{
    int i;
    *my_s = (my_struct_t *)realloc(*my_s, sizeof(my_struct_t)*num); 
    for (i = 0; i < num; i++ ) {
        (*my_s)[i].one = 1*i;
        (*my_s)[i].two = 2*i;
    }
    printf("  (*my_s)[0] one: %d two: %d\n", (*my_s)[0].one, (*my_s)[0].two);
}
```

You can then call it like this.

```
my_struct_t *my_structs = NULL;
...
update_my_struct(&my_structs, 4);
```

This will work fine for one initialization and the number of structs allocated is kept by the caller. A second call will reallocate to the new number of structs, and reinitialize everything from the beginning.
I omitted `realloc` return value check for brevity.

And here is the full code as tested on godbolt.

```
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <stdio.h>

  typedef struct my_struct {
    int one;
    int two;
} my_struct_t;
    
    void
    update_my_struct(my_struct_t **my_s, int num)
    {
        int i;
        *my_s = (my_struct_t *)realloc(*my_s, sizeof(my_struct_t)*num); 
        for (i = 0; i < num; i++ ) {
            (*my_s)[i].one = 1*i;
            (*my_s)[i].two = 2*i;
        }
    }

    my_struct_t *my_structs = NULL;

    int main ()
    {
        int i;
        update_my_struct(&my_structs, 4);

        for (int i=0; i<4; i++)
            printf("  (*my_s)[%d] one: %d two: %d\n", i, my_structs[i].one, my_structs[i].two);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but I really need the realloc inside the loop in my real life code. Your proposed solution kind of works, but now I get seg faults in the update function after the first iteration, so it works once and fails to assign values to the struct after the second realloc.

Comment: Do you pass the same global in the second call or something else?

Comment: Not the second call the function, but the second iteration of the for loop inside the update function - the seg fault occurs when i=1.

Comment: Interestingly the seg fault occurs in the same place regardless of the realloc line being inside or outside of the loop (like in your proposed solution).

Comment: I don't see how you get a segfault. This code works fine on godbolt after fixing a little typo `my_struct_s` to `my_struct_t`.

Comment: OK, my bad - I used `->` instead of `(* )`. It does work fine now, thanks.

Comment: You got me wondering there for a second :)

Answer (score 0):

Check your `realloc` docs: the memory must have been previously allocated with with `malloc`/etc, or the results are undefined.

Your code doesn't really work either - the `realloc` is inside your `for` loop, etc.

And try running `valgrind` - it would have found this problem.

Comment: I changed it to: `malloc if NULL else realloc` also with the type cast to `my_struct_t *`, but it did not solve the problem.

Comment: @mac13k: you should post your new code, and run `valgrind` if you can.

Comment: And your suggested change won't work anyway - 'undefined behaviour' is not the same as as checking the return value for 0. Just do a `malloc` in main.

Comment: Why can't I do the malloc in the included function?

Comment: Yuo can do it wherever you want; just do a stand-alone malloc as the first step.

Comment: But in my real code I do not know whether there are any instances of a struct to be added to the array or not, so if there is nothing the pointer should be empty which malloc will set its size to `sizeof(my_struct)` suggesting there is one element.

Comment: Generally you can't pass an uninitialized pointer to realloc. You can however pass a NULL pointer and then it behaves just as malloc. And by accident, the OP is indeed passing a NULL pointer, since the global pointer has static storage duration. So this answer is incorrect for this specific case.