# How to resize a hashtable in C? Array refuses to change

Tags: c, struct, hashtable

```
struct table
  {
    int size;
    key_value *array[];
  };

struct table *create_table(int size)
{
    struct table *table = calloc(1, sizeof(struct table));
    table->size = size;
    return table;
}

void resize_table(struct table *table, int new_size)
{
    struct table *new_table = create_table(new_size);
    for(int i = 0; i < table->size; i++)
      {
      key_value *p = table->array[i]->next;
      while(has_next(p))
        {
        insert(new_table, p->key, p->value);
        p = p->next;
        }
      }
    *table = *new_table;
}
```

I tried making the array only `array[]`, this didn't work either. When I try to get rehashed values through  `new_table`, it works perfectly. But after assigning `*table = *new_table` and accessing rehashed values through `table`, it doesn't work. Why does `assert(new_table->array[23]->key==23)` work, but not `assert(table->array[23]->key==23)`? I have put table equal to new_table, shouldn't they be the same now?
What's weird is that the `size` value has changed, but not the array.

When I try to change just the pointer:

```
table->array = new_table->array;
```

I get `invalid use of flexible array member`, which I don't understand, aren't I just changing a pointer in the struct to a different adress, why does it even matter that it's an array?

Can I solve this by using alloc/realloc maybe?

Comment: You should show us how you create the hashtable or insert into it. Also how do you call the function you showed? Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You can never assign structures holding a flexible array member to another variable. The compiler does not know the size of your array. You can only do this using dynamic memory allocation and manually keeping track of the sizes.

Comment: Also: You can never assign an array to another array. You can only initialize arrays or copy members of arrays. "When I try to change just the pointer:" `array` is not a pointer but an arrays of pointers.

Comment: Why are you making up the code in your question, instead of just _pasting_ the minimal verifiable example you already have? And why are you describing a compiler error instead of just _pasting_ it and showing which line it refers to?

Comment: `*table = *new_table` will only copy the `size` member and any padding before the `array` member. It will not copy the flexible array member.

Comment: Stop providing code that you retyped but doesn't resemble what you are actually compiling. Show some real code with real error messages.

Comment: "Can I solve this by using alloc/realloc maybe?" Unless that's what `create_table` is already doing, you have some massive bugs all over the place. Please post the code for that function.

Comment: Create_table uses malloc, can I use realloc to increase the array size somehow?

Comment: Yes, no, maybe. Since you don't appear to know what a flexible array member is, then I have reason to believe that `create_table` isn't correctly implemented (either).

Comment: Quote: **"aren't I just changing a pointer in the struct to a different adress"** NO, because there is no pointer in the struct! What you have is a flexible array.

Comment: Most likely you want `key_value *array[];` --> `key_value **array;`

Comment: @4386427 Not necessarily. An array of pointers makes perfect sense for a hash table implementing "chaining" (a linked list of items per duplicate hash index). A pointer-to-pointer not so much, unless it points to the first pointer in an array of pointers.

Comment: Ok I'll vote re-open and try to answer after last edit. (My dupehammer clicked apparently, gonna need 2 more votes...)

Comment: `table->size = size;` Is `size` meant to indicate the size of the array? You have memory for 0 elements allocated, no matter what `size` is.

Comment: In case it doesn't get re-opened, then as I predicted by "gut debugging", `create_table` is all wrong too. This whole code needs to be rewritten.

Comment: @Lundin From both the posted code and text, it seems that OP doesn't know the flexible array concept but thinks of `array` as a pointer. Therefore I assume OP wants a pointer.

Comment: @Lundin There is still much code missing. And we don't know what OP is trying. So perhaps it's too early to reopen

Comment: There are several problems here: when it is appropriate to hard-copy a struct and when it is not. How to copy arrays in C. How flexible array members work. How passing dynamically allocated data back from a function. And so on. I could write an answer addressing at least these issues, though there may be more of them.

Comment: Sounds good, my program worked well before, when the table was fixed (array[24]), C-unit tests & valgrind no leaks. Just having problems with making it dynamic right now which is tied to me not understanding those things you listed.

Comment: `create_table` is not allocating any space for the flexible array member. Is it meant to? If it is supposed to allocate space for `size` elements, then it should be something like `struct table *table = malloc(sizeof(struct table) + size * sizeof (key_value));`. Then I guess you need a loop to set the array elements to null pointers.

Comment: @IanAbbott No, it requires `sizeof (key_value*)`

Comment: @4386427 Yes, you are correct. Sorry!

Comment: Either the first parameter of `resize_table` should  be of type `struct table **` or it should return a pointer to the new `struct table`.

Comment: The part inside `resize_table`'s `for` loop where it is transferring key-value pairs from the old table to the new table looks like it is skipping the first and last elements of the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of misconceptions here.

- `key_value *array[];` is a so-called *flexible array member*, a special feature. Specifically it is an array of `key_value` pointers, of a size unknown at the point of declaration. It is an array, not a pointer.

  Therefore `table->array = new_table->array;` tries to assign an array to another array, which isn't allowed in C. Arrays must be copied with `memcpy` or similar.
- Flexible array members mostly make sense when you need to allocate adjacent memory directly following the struct. A hash table isn't an obvious use-case for such, but it can be made to work (and gives good cache performance). What you need to do when allocating a flex array member is to allocate room for the struct and the array in one go, like this:

  ```
  struct table *table = calloc(1, sizeof(struct table) + sizeof(key_value*[size]) );
  ```

  A special attribute of flexible array members is that `sizeof(struct table)` doesn't take the flex array in account. So we need to specify that size separately.

  If you don't do this, then `key_value` isn't valid memory and can't be used.

  `calloc` can be assumed to set all pointers to null, so that's good, keep `calloc` instead of `malloc` which doesn't init anything.
- This here won't work:

  ```
  void resize_table(struct table *table, int new_size)
  {
    struct table *new_table = create_table(new_size);
  ```

  For the reasons explained at [Dynamic memory access only works inside function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39486797/dynamic-memory-access-only-works-inside-function)

  There are two ways you could make this work:

  - Either `table` is assumed to point at previously allocated data. In that case you should not call `create_table` but modify the already allocated data. Possibly `realloc` it. In which case realloc must look use `sizeof(struct table) + sizeof(key_value*[new_size])`.

    `realloc`, unlike `calloc`, does not initialize the data to zero, so you must do that explicitly for the new items if you use `realloc`.
  - Or alternatively you can ask the caller to provide you with an address to the previously allocated data, through `struct table** table`. Then you can `free` it and then just call `create_table` anew, storing the result inside `*table`. Naturally you might want to `memcpy` over any items that should be preserved before calling `free` though.
- Similarly, `*table = *new_table;` won't work since that will not copy the flexible array member, nor any data pointed at by the pointers it contains.

  But in general one cannot hard copy a struct when it has pointer members to dynamically allocated data, or you end up with two structs where the members point at the same data. This means that you would have to allocate all data anew using either of the two methods I described above.

Note that all of the above merely allocates room for the pointers themselves in `key_value *array[]`. They have to be set to point at actual data allocated elsewhere, outside this struct.

Comment: If I go the flexible array member route, can I use realloc to increase the size on the array afterwards?

Comment: @Blue Yes, that's what the answer says - you must realloc everything including the struct.

Answer (score 0):

When you originally had

```
struct table
  {
    int size;
    key_value *array[24];
  };
```

(or whatever), the fixed-size 24-element array is part of your struct, and is counted in `sizeof(struct table)`, and space is allocated for it correctly in

```
struct table *create_table(int size)
{
    struct table *table = calloc(1, sizeof(struct table));
    table->size = size;
    return table;
}
```

But when you change this to a flexible array, it has no default size, and no storage for it is assumed in `sizeof(struct table)`. This should be obvious, because you've explicitly told the compiler you don't *know* how big it should be. You could easily confirm your understanding here by just printing `sizeof` the two versions of your struct.

Therefore, you need to explicitly tell `calloc` how many extra bytes to allocate:

```
    struct table *table = calloc(1, sizeof(struct table) + size * sizeof(key_value*));
```

Finally, the assignment

```
  *table = *new_table;
```

won't work either, because the two objects are not necessarily the same size. You can't resize the first object (whose array length the compiler doesn't even know) like this, and no elements will be copied from the flexible array either (because the compiler doesn't know how many there are).

Now, you already allocated an object of the correct size - You need to return this to the caller. The usual approach would be to pass a pointer-to-pointer, so you can update the caller with the new address:

```
void resize_table(struct table **table_ptr, int new_size)
{
    struct table *table = *table_ptr; /* this is just to avoid rewriting the rest of the code */
    struct table *new_table = create_table(new_size);
    for(int i = 0; i < table->size; i++)
      {
      key_value *p = table->array[i]->next;
      while(has_next(p))
        {
        insert(new_table, p->key, p->value);
        p = p->next;
        }
      }
    *table_ptr = new_table;
    free(table); /* you're replacing the table, not updating it */
}
```

There are potentially other problems, like the fact that you seem to always skip the first element in a bucket, and you *could* use `realloc` to reduce the number of redundant calloc/free operations.

Answer (score 0):

Since `array` inside the struct is without a size specification, it's a flexible array member and it needs dynamic memory allocation. Your code never do that so your `array` has no memory. You can implement it using a flexible array but for this I would go for a pointer to pointer to `key_value`.

Like:

```
struct table
{
    int size;
    key_value **array;
};

struct table *create_table(int size)
{
    struct table *table = malloc(sizeof *table);
    assert(table != NULL);
    table->size = size;
    table->array = calloc(size, sizeof *table->array);
    assert(table->array != NULL);
    return table;
}

void resize_table(struct table *table, int new_size)
{
    key_value **tmp = realloc(table->array, new_size * sizeof *table->array);
    if (tmp == NULL)
    {
        // Error handling or just:
        exit(1);
    }
    table->size = new_size;
    table->array = tmp;
}
```

If you prefer a solution using a flexible array member, it would something like:

```
struct table
{
    int size;
    key_value *array[];
};

struct table *create_table(int size)
{
    struct table *table = calloc(1, sizeof *table + size * sizeof table->array[0]);
    assert(table != NULL);
    table->size = size;
    return table;
}

struct table * resize_table(struct table *table, int new_size)
{
    struct table *tmp = realloc(table, sizeof *table + new_size * sizeof table->array[0]);
    if (tmp == NULL)
    {
        // Error handling or just:
        exit(1);
    }
    tmp->size = new_size;
    return tmp;
}
```

and use the `resize_table` like:

```
table = resize_table(table, new_size);
```