# Fill a dynamic 2D array with words of multiples text files in C

Tags: arrays, c, char, readdir

with this C code I want to fill a dynamic array of char with the words parsed in each differents text files returned by the `readdir` function.

```
#include <string.h>                                                             
#include <malloc.h>                                                             
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

                                            
char *getWord(FILE *fp){
    char word[100];
    int ch, i=0;

    while(EOF!=(ch=fgetc(fp)) && !isalpha(ch))
        ;//skip
    if(ch == EOF)
        return NULL;
    do{
        word[i++] = tolower(ch);
    }while(EOF!=(ch=fgetc(fp)) && isalpha(ch));

    word[i]='\0';
    return strdup(word);
}

int readWords(const char * fn,char ** arr){
    char *word;
    FILE * fp;
    int size=0;
    //read first time to get the number of words
    fp=fopen(fn,"r");

    while(word=getWord(fp)){
        size++;
    }

    fclose(fp);
    printf("size:%d\n",size);
    arr = (char **) malloc (size * sizeof (char *));
    //reopen to insert in dynamic array
    fp=fopen(fn,"r");
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        arr[i] = (char *) malloc (100 * sizeof (char));
        word=getWord(fp);
        // printf("%s",word);
        strcpy(arr[i],word);
    }
    fclose(fp);

    return size;
}

int main(int narg, char *arg[] )
{
    struct dirent *de;  // Pointer for directory entry
    char absdir[256];
    char absfn[256];
    FILE * F;
    int s;

    // opendir() returns a pointer of DIR type. 
    DIR *dr = opendir(arg[1]);
    strcpy(absdir,arg[1]);
    strcat(absdir,"/");

  
    if (dr == NULL)  // opendir returns NULL if couldn't open directory
    {
        printf("Could not open current directory" );
        return 0;
    }
  

    while ((de = readdir(dr)) != NULL){
        if (de->d_type!=4){ // is file?
            strcpy(absfn,absdir);
            strcat(absfn,de->d_name);
            printf("abs_fn:%s \n",absfn);
            char** arr_words;

            s=readWords(absfn,&arr_words);

            printf("%s number of words:%d\n", absfn,s);
            for (int i=0;i<s;i++)
                printf("word %d:%s\n",i,arr_words[i]);
            
            //free 2D array

            for(int i=0;i<s;i++)
                free(arr_words[i]);
            free(arr_words);

        }
            
    }
    closedir(dr);    
    return 0;
}
```

the words are well parsed with `getWord` but i can't find the solution to fill the `char **arr passed` in argument and to use it latter in the main function.
I want to allocated the `char **arr_words`  dynamically with  the following form

```
arr_words[0]=First word of file text
arr_words[1]=Second word
arr_words[s-1]=Last Word
```

the `Readword` function return the number of words read in each files.

thanks

Comment: This isn't a 2D array. It is a 1D array of pointers, each pointing to a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your bug is a more advanced one of the problem described here: [Dynamic memory access only works inside function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39486797/dynamic-memory-access-only-works-inside-function)

`arr` is a local variable. It's a *pointer to the first pointer in an array of pointers*. In order to return this to main (hang on tight now), your function need to pass a pointer to a *pointer to the first pointer in an array of pointers*...

Or in plain C, the dreaded three-star programming, `char***`. But this is actually a valid use for it, about the only valid use of three levels of indirection that exists.

Alternatively, you can just use the return for the `char**` and skip this extra level of indirection, which might be more readable.

Which form to use is a bit subjective, but you need to change your function to one of these:

```
int readWords(const char * fn, char*** arr)
{
  ... 
  *arr = malloc (size * sizeof (char *))
  ...
}
```

or

```
char** readWords(const char * fn, int* wordsRead)
{
   ...
   arr = malloc (size * sizeof (char *));
   ...
   *wordsRead = size;
   return arr;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! it works like a charm. For convenient I choose the second solution...but with a bit sadness to not use a three stars for the first time of my life ;). I post the working code just below.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <string.h>                                                             
#include <malloc.h>                                                             
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

                                            
char *getWord(FILE *fp){
    char word[100];
    int ch, i=0;

    while(EOF!=(ch=fgetc(fp)) && !isalpha(ch))
        ;//skip
    if(ch == EOF)
        return NULL;
    do{
        word[i++] = tolower(ch);
    }while(EOF!=(ch=fgetc(fp)) && isalpha(ch));

    word[i]='\0';
    return strdup(word);
}

char** readWords(const char * fn,int *wordsRead){
    char *word;
    char**arr;
    FILE * fp;
    int size=0;
    //read first time to get the number of words
    fp=fopen(fn,"r");

    while(word=getWord(fp)){
        size++;
    }

    fclose(fp);
    printf("size:%d\n",size);
    arr = malloc (size * sizeof (char *));
    //reopen to insert in dynamic array
    fp=fopen(fn,"r");
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        arr[i] = (char *) malloc (100 * sizeof (char));
        word=getWord(fp);
        // printf("%s",word);
        strcpy(arr[i],word);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    *wordsRead = size;

    return arr;
}



int main(int narg, char *arg[] )
{
    struct dirent *de;  // Pointer for directory entry
    char absdir[256];
    char absfn[256];
    FILE * F;
    int s;
    int wordsRead;
    char buffer[100];

    // opendir() returns a pointer of DIR type. 
    DIR *dr = opendir(arg[1]);
    strcpy(absdir,arg[1]);
    strcat(absdir,"/");

  
    if (dr == NULL)  // opendir returns NULL if couldn't open directory
    {
        printf("Could not open current directory" );
        return 0;
    }
  

    while ((de = readdir(dr)) != NULL){
        if (de->d_type!=4){ // is file?
            strcpy(absfn,absdir);
            strcat(absfn,de->d_name);
            printf("abs_fn:%s \n",absfn);
            char **arr_words;
            arr_words=readWords(absfn,&wordsRead);

            printf("%s number of words:%d\n", absfn,wordsRead);
            for (int i=0;i<wordsRead;i++){
                
                printf("word %d:%s\n",i,arr_words[i]);
            }
            //free array of pointers

            for(int i=0;i<s;i++)
                free(arr_words[i]);
            free(arr_words);

        }
            
    }
    closedir(dr);    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).