# Why single pointer as argument can't modify a string (in c)

Tags: c, pointers, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value, double-pointer

By using a double pointer as argument in a function, the program below can modify the string, I understand.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void display(char** output)
{
    printf("%s\n", *output);
    *output = "This is another test";
}

int main(void)
{
    char* str = "This is a test";
    display(&str);
    printf("After the call: %s\n", str);
    return 0;
}
```

However, I don't understand why using a single pointer as argument like below can't modify the string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void display(char* output)
{
    printf("%s\n", output);
    output = "This is another test";
    printf("%s\n", output);
}

int main(void)
{
    char* str = "This is a test";
    display(str);
    printf("After the call: %s\n", str);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In c arguments are always passed by value. In the 2nd you pass the pointer itself. It is passed by value and therefore changing `output` in `func` modifies the copy and does not affect the caller. In the 1st one you still pass by value (as always), but you pass the address of the pointer. Using the address you can modify the pointer of the caller (`*output = ...`).

Comment: Why can you modify the pointer by using an address of a pointer in function?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39486797/dynamic-memory-access-only-works-inside-function, the answer explains it.

Comment: Be aware that in C *all* parameters are passed *by value* to functions. This means the values are *copied*. Always, full stop. This applies for pointers as well. So if you assign to the parameter in second example you modify the copy. This applies for the double pointer, too, if you do not dereference it. On dereferencing you modify that this double pointer points to – and this is the single pointer outside the function...

Comment: Note, that you – albeit legal – shouldn't ever assign string literals to pointers to non-const char! That way you run the risk of accidentally modifying them, which is undefined behaviour. And if your code gets complex you *will* end up doing so some day...

Comment: Also read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766893/how-do-i-modify-a-pointer-that-has-been-passed-into-a-function-in-c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may imagine the function and its call in the second shown program the following way

```
char* str = "This is a test";
display(str);

//...

void display( /* char* output */ )
{
    char *output = str;

    printf("%s\n", output);
    output = "This is another test";
    printf("%s\n", output);
}
```

That is the argument expression `str` is used to initialize the function local variable `output`. And within the function it is its local variable `output` that is being changed. The pointer `str` used as an initializer of the function local variable stays unchanged. The function does not deal with `str` except of using it to initialize its parameter `output`.

To change an object within a function you need to pass it to the function by reference.

In C passing by reference means passing an object indirectly through a pointer to it. Thus dereferencing the pointer the function has a direct access to the object pointed to by the pointer and can change it. And your first program demonstrates this approach.

Dereferencing the pointer `output`

```
*output = "This is another test";
```

the function has a direct access to the pointer `str` declared in main and passed to the function through a pointer to it

```
display(&str);
```

and changes it.

Comment: Isn't it UB, though, since the code modifies a string literal defined using `char *` instead of `char []`?

Comment: @FabiosaysReinstateMonica The function does not change any string literal. It changes values of pointers themselves. String literals stay unchanged.

Comment: Ah, you are right, sorry!

Answer (score 1):

You can't assign an argument in function.

```c
void func(int* a) {
    int b = 0;
    *a = b; // that'll work.
    a = &b; // that doesn't.
}
```

Use a `char**` to do what you want.

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not much of an explanation _why_, is it...