# What is the proper way to dereference or reference so that I can simply allocate the memory needed for this array of structs?

Tags: c

```
void readPixelsBMP(FILE* file, struct Pixel** pArr, int width, int height) {
        int size = width * height;
        *pArr = (struct Pixel*) malloc(size * sizeof(struct Pixel));
        if (*pArr == NULL) {
            printf("Error! Insufficient memory!");
            return;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
            //this line gives an error \/
             (*pArr)[i] = (struct Pixel*)malloc(width * sizeof(struct Pixel));
            }
        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
                //this line gives an error \/
                fread(&((*pArr)[i][j]), sizeof(struct Pixel), 1, file);
            }
        }
        fclose(file);
}
```

`(pArr)[i] = (struct Pixel)malloc(width * sizeof(struct Pixel));` throws an error saying incompatable types but I tried every version of referencing and dereferencing that I could think of. And then it does not like the line `fread(&((*pArr)[i][j]), sizeof(struct Pixel), 1, file);` probably for the same reason. I am not sure how I include the array part and properly reference/dereference.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  What is it that you are having trouble with?  What is this proverbial wall you're hitting?

Comment: (*pArr)[i] = (struct Pixel*)malloc(width * sizeof(struct Pixel)); throws an error saying incompatable types but I tried every version of referencing and dereferencing that I could think of. And then it does not like the line fread(&((*pArr)[i][j]), sizeof(struct Pixel), 1, file); probably for the same reason. I am not sure how I include the array part and properly reference/dereference.

Comment: Please include that information in your original post and not in the comments.

Comment: How many times are you planning on reposting versions of this question? There were answers provided to the version giving you problems about 24hrs ago that this code simply ignores.

Comment: I would urge you to stop taking a chance when writing C. There are too many bugs here caused by not understanding the concepts of arrays and pointers before moving on to dynamic allocation. You _can't_ program by guessing or trial & error - you have to actually know what each line you type does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many problems here.

The main one being that you cannot return a pointer to pointer array `struct Pixel**` through a parameter. Start by studying [Dynamic memory access only works inside function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39486797/dynamic-memory-access-only-works-inside-function) and learn why your function here won't work.

The next problem is `(*pArr)[i]`, here you de-reference the pointer twice and end up with a struct object rather than a pointer to one which is needed for the result of `malloc`.

Another big problem is that this way of allocation is conceptually and fundamentally wrong. You are allocating an array of pointers where you should be allocating a 2D array. See [Correctly allocating multi-dimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays) for details.

But your first malloc actually allocates a contiguous chunk by doing `malloc(size * sizeof(struct Pixel))`. That can be made to work by using a "mangled 2D array" - which is to have a plain struct pointer point at the start of the array and then calculate indices as `[i*width + j]`. But it's a less readable syntax than `[i][j]`. As you noted, `(*pArr)[i][j])` is not correct either given a pointer-to-pointer.

Your for loops are not consistent with the array. If you mean the array to be represented as `arr[width][height]` then the outer for loop must iterate across `width` and the inner one across `height`. C places no meaning to width/height, but the left-most dimension of a 2D array needs to correspond to the outer loop.

---

So how to fix all of this? There's too many bugs, we have to start over. While doing so we could introduce an actual 2D array instead of an array of pointers. We could use the concept of variable-length arrays (VLA) to match the width/height parameters with the array.

The syntax of this might be a bit intimidating, but if we want our array to be type `struct Pixel arr[width][height];` then a pointer to such an array is declared as `struct Pixel (*arr)[width][height];`.

And then for the reasons explained in the first link I gave, we have to pass this pointer by reference or the changes in the function won't transfer back to the caller.

So your main() might become something like this:

```c
int width = 3;
int height = 5;
struct Pixel (*arr)[width][height];

readPixelsBMP(file, width, height, &arr);
...

(*arr)[i][j] = ... ; // use the pointed-at array
...

free(arr);
```

And the suitable, corrected function might look like this:

```c
void readPixelsBMP(FILE* file, int width, int height, struct Pixel (**pArr)[width][height]) {
    *pArr = malloc( sizeof(struct Pixel[width][height]) );
    if (*pArr == NULL) {
        printf("Error! Insufficient memory!");
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
            fread(*pArr, sizeof(struct Pixel), 1, file);
        }
    }
    fclose(file);
}
```

Comment: "_The bits representing the bitmap pixels are packed in rows (also known as strides or scan lines). The size of each row is rounded up to a multiple of 4 bytes (a 32-bit DWORD) by padding._" -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format

Comment: @Fe2O3 We can worry about that once the numerous, fundamental bugs are fixed. For example reading a struct directly from a file is also questionable.